# Adding a Custom Phone Number Field On Azure AD B2C SignUp Page

Tags: java, android, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have integrated `Azure AD B2C` on my Android Native App. I have created the `userflows` for `SignInSignUp`  and it was working as expected. I would like to add an extra field naming `PhoneNumber` on signUp Page and I need to Provide some Validation to the `phoneNumber` Field . How can that be done on azure AD b2c?

Answer (score 3):

It’s explained end to end here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes

Comment: I have added the attributes , but i would like to know, how can i provide some validation for the newly added attribute. In my case i have added a new attribute `PhoneNumber`.

Comment: By [enabling the javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-javascript-overview) you can do validation on the fields. Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples#javascript-samples) for more information